# Pivot a BigQuery table without PIVOT

Tags: google-bigquery

Let's say you have a Google BigQuery subquery that yields the following 3-column table, shown as CSV here....and another wrinkle is needing to run as a "bq" command in a DOS Window (CMD.EXE) in one single step--no scripted sequence of commands are possible.

```
service, usagedate, cost
Cats, 2023-07-05, 440.51
Cats, 2023-07-06, 368.36
Cats, 2023-07-07, 0.00
Dogs, 2023-07-05, 10.90
Dogs, 2023-07-06, 10.78
Dogs, 2023-07-07, 3.88
```

Here is the approach I tried, but this doesn't work because the SELECT for the today and yesterday columns returns multiple rows with the same date. An alternative, the native PIVOT directive doesn't work, because it demands a list of constant column header values. Whereas my use case requires dynamic ones (dates nearby "today").

```
WITH (*foo*) AS subquery SELECT DISTINCT service, (SELECT cost FROM subquery WHERE usagedate = CURRENT_DATE()) AS A, (SELECT cost FROM subquery WHERE usagedate = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as B FROM subquery
```

My objective is to yield a table like this:

```
service, A, B
Cats, 454.43, 455.04
Dogs, 10.86, 10.90
```

Can you think of a way to select out the distinct service values in column 1, and show a succession of (variable) dates as columns on that same row?  Thanks, Stackoverflow!

P.S. "Later" I convert the first row to replace "A" with the actual date, that seems more feasible than trying to get dates as column headers.

Here is the whole hacked together mess, will look at simplifying later but "it works" using Mikhail's excellent guidance!  Five stars!

```
call bq query --quiet --format=csv --max_rows=1234567890 --use_legacy_sql=false "WITH  snip AS ( SELECT DISTINCT service.description AS SERVICE,    service.id AS ID, cast(usage_end_time as date) as UsageDate,  SUM(cost) + SUM(IFNULL((SELECT SUM(c.amount) FROM UNNEST(credits) c where c.name not like 'migration-credit%%'),0)) AS COST FROM %targetdataset%  WHERE service.id in(select distinct service.id from %targetdataset%  WHERE  project.id = '%projectid%'    and    cast(usage_end_time as date) > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 day))   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 ORDER BY SERVICE, UsageDate DESC ), snip2 as (SELECT DISTINCT SERVICE, ID, UsageDate, sum(COST) as COST from snip where UsageDate > date_sub(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 10 day)  and COST > 0 GROUP BY 1, 2, 3), snip3 as (select SERVICE,   sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 9, COST, 0)) A, sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 8, COST, 0)) B,  sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 7, COST, 0)) C,  sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 6, COST, 0)) D, sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 5, COST, 0)) E,  sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 4, COST, 0)) F,  sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 3, COST, 0)) G,  sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 2, COST, 0)) H,  sum(if(UsageDate = current_date - 1, COST, 0)) I,  sum(if(UsageDate = current_date, COST, 0)) J,  from snip2 group by SERVICE) select SERVICE, trim(cast(A as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(B as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(C as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(D as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(E as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(F as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(G as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(H as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(I as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), trim(cast(J as STRING FORMAT '99999990.99')), from snip3 order by 1 "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider below approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
select service, 
  sum(if(usagedate = current_date, cost, 0)) A,
  sum(if(usagedate = current_date - 1, cost, 0)) B
from subquery
group by service
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

P.S. you can use below for quick test

```
with subquery as (
  select 'Cats' service, date '2023-07-05' usagedate, 440.51 cost union all
  select 'Cats', '2023-07-06', 368.36 union all
  select 'Cats', '2023-07-07', 0.00 union all
  select 'Dogs', '2023-07-05', 10.90 union all
  select 'Dogs', '2023-07-06', 10.78 union all
  select 'Dogs', '2023-07-07', 3.88 
)
select service, 
  sum(if(usagedate = current_date, cost, 0)) A,
  sum(if(usagedate = current_date - 1, cost, 0)) B
from subquery
group by service
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mikhail, this helped a ton!  For fun, I pasted the final answer above but it's sort of hard to see in the scrolling box.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (with PIVOT)

```
select * from (
  select * except(usagedate), 
    case 
      when usagedate = current_date then 'today'
      when usagedate = current_date - 1 then 'yesterday'
      when usagedate > current_date - 7 then 'prev_7_days' 
    end as day 
  from subquery
)
pivot (sum(cost) for day in ('today', 'yesterday', 'prev_7_days'))
```

if to apply to sample data in your question  - output is

[image]